# Youtube javascript api, pjax, how to reload onYouTubeIframeAPIReady();

Tags: youtube-javascript-api, pjax

I have a problem with the youtube javascript player api.

I call this js code :

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  var podcast = document.getElementById('podcast')
  var player = new YT.Player( document.getElementById('podcast'));
  player.addEventListener('onStateChange', function(e) {
    if (e.data === 1) {
      alert("play");
    }
  });
};
```

with this html code :

```
<iframe id="podcast" type="text/html" width="720" height="405"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XXXXXX?cc_load_policy=1&enablejsapi=1&theme=light"
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
```

The problem is that I use the pjax system, so the global javascript code is not reloaded when I navigate.
So, I reload some part of my javascript code when pjax:success. I tried something like this :

```
$(document).on('pjax:success', function() {
  onYouTubeIframeAPIReady();
}
```

but it doesn't work. My question is how to reload onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(); when it must to be defined globally as it is said there [onYouTubeIframeAPIReady function is not calling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26780291/onyoutubeiframeapiready-function-is-not-calling)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When my player is defined I don't use onYoutubePlayerAPIReady. It's the best solution I find, and it works.

```
var player = {
    playVideo: function(container, videoId) {
        if (typeof(YT) == 'undefined' || typeof(YT.Player) == 'undefined') {
            window.onYouTubePlayerAPIReady = function() {
                player.loadPlayer(container, videoId);
            };
            $.getScript('//www.youtube.com/player_api');
        } else {
            player.loadPlayer(container, videoId);
        }
    },
    loadPlayer: function(container, videoId) {
        window.myPlayer = new YT.Player(container, 
            height: 200,
            width: 200,
            videoId: videoId,
        });
    }
};


var containerId = 'podcast';
var videoId = '<%= @youtube_id %>';
player.playVideo(containerId, videoId);
```